# correct sql syntax for compound conditionals of the same attribute

Tags: mysql, sql

I am very new to sql.

Is there a way to make something like the following statement less wordy?

`...WHERE state = "PA" OR state = "NJ" OR state = "CA" or state = "NY" or state = "FL" OR state = "CO"` etc...

I have tried: `WHERE state = ("PA" OR "NJ" etc...)` but that did not work.

I am sure that my question has been answered, however I can not think of a way to word it to get any results.  I am very new to the language so I don't know the names of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IN`.

**Query**

```
select * from your_table_name
where state in ('PA','NJ','CA','NY','FL','NO');
```